# How can I get the IP of a container in a specific network_mode from another container outside of that mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a project there are three services in the docker compose yml:

A VPN.

A container (named `first`) connected to that VPN using network_mode.

A container (named `second`) not connected to that VPN.

From `first` I can get `second`'s IP using the container name (second), but the oposite does not work.

"first" and "second" are simple python scripts sending data to each other using socket.

I can send data from "second" to "first" if I use the IP address instead of the container name, but that is not a solution I can use in the project.

This is the .yml I'm using:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    vpn:
        build: ./vpn
        container_name: vpn
        env_file:
            - ss.env
        cap_add: 
            - NET_ADMIN
            - NET_RAW
        devices:
            - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
        dns:
            - 1.1.1.1

    first:
        build: ./first
        container_name: first
        depends_on: 
            - vpn
        network_mode: service:vpn

    second:
        build: ./second
        container_name: second
        depends_on: 
            - vpn
```

The relevant part of the python scripts:

```
#first.py
client.sendto(bytes('message from second',encoding='utf8'), ('second', 37021))

#second.py
client.sendto(bytes('message from second',encoding='utf8'), ('first', 37020))
```

Also, the vpn log:

```
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.8.2/24
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip route add 104.111.100.109/32 via 192.168.144.1
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1
vpn       | 2021-10-20 00:44:21 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems come from a misconfiguration of the networks.

First of all, when you're starting services with `docker-compose up -d` you're creating a default network with the name of the folder where that Compose file is located. You can check that with `docker network ls`.

Well, all your services will connect by default to that network, except if you define a different default **or you change the network mode**, as it's your case for `first`.

Basically, let's suppose you have your Compose file under a directory called `myapp`.

1. When you start your containers, Docker Compose is creating a network with the name `myapp-default`.
2. Your services `vpn` and `second` will join that network, but `first` will work with the network stack from `vpn`.
3. Since `first` is using the same network namespace of `vpn`, it can discover `second` without any problem using the service name.
4. Since `first` isn't in the `default` network, `second` cannot discover it.

If you want `first` to be discoverable by `second` you shouldn't use the same network stack of `vpn` but just let it join the `default` network created by Compose (or create another network by yourself and make the three of them to join that network).

Comment: Thank you @daniel-campos, it certainly explains why I'm having that problem and makes me understand docker networking a lot more.

The problem with your solution is that, from my limited understanding, I think it will make "first" stop using "vpn" network, and the goal is to make "first" do its thing using "vpn"'s ip address, while still being able to connect to "second".

Comment: That's not a problem, since `first` will always be able to discover `second`. Your issue comes when you want to discover `first` from `second` when this one isn't in the same network... Have you thought about the possibility of routing the traffic through `vpn`? `second` would communicate with `vpn` and this one would forward the requests/messages to `first`. Other option would be to send the IP from `first` in an initial message to `second`, you can get it from the same container with `ip -4 -o address`.

Comment: "Other option would be to send the IP from first in an initial message to second".

<- That is the solution I'm currently using, it's probably the best way to do it without rebuilding the whole project.

Thank you very much for your time and answers!

Comment: You're welcome!